# insert multiple urls into inputfields from multiple values

Tags: javascript, extjs, fetch

I have a fetch get request that parse page and get some parametrs to generate new url and insert it into input fields
I have multiple values from `value1`, `value2`, `value3`
The question is that how i can generate multiple urls from this parametrs and insert it into fields(fields should generate dynamically)?
Now, window with form dont generates

If i put `break` into loop, code generate window with form but show only one url

As a result of this code should be Window with form and three input fields with urls

```js
var url = 'google.com/page1'
fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.text()
    })
    .then(function(html) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
            var value4 = 'test4';
            var UrlArr = [];
            if (condition) {
                var name = doc.querySelectorAll("someClass");
                for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                    var allNames = name[i].outerHTML;
                    var value1 = allNames.match('MyregExp1')[0];
                    var value2 = allNames.match('MyregExp2')[0];
                    var value3 = allNames.match('MYregExp3')[0];

                    var newUrl = `google.com/?${value1}&${value2}&${value3}&test=${value4}`;
                    //brake

                    console.log(value1);
                    // something1
                    // something2
                    // something3
                    // etc...

                    console.log(value2);
                    // something11
                    // something22
                    // something33
                    // etc...

                    console.log(value3);
                    // something111
                    // something222
                    // something333
                    // etc...


                    UrlArr.push(newUrl);
                    console.log(UrlArr);
                    //first-array
                    // [google.com/?something1&something2&$something3&test=test4]
                    // 0: google.com/?something1&something2&$something3&test=test4
                    // 1: google.com/?something11&something22&$something33&test=test4
                    // 2: google.com/?something111&something222&$something333&test=test4

                    // second-array
                    // [google.com/?something1&something2&$something3&test=test4,google.com/?something11&something22&$something33&test=test4 ]
                    // 0: google.com/?something1&something2&$something3&test=test4
                    // 1: google.com/?something11&something22&$something33&test=test4
                    // 2: google.com/?something111&something222&$something333&test=test4

                    // third-array
                    // [google.com/?something1&something2&$something3&test=test4,google.com/?something11&something22&$something33&test=test4,google.com/?something111&something222&$something333&test=test4]
                    // 0: google.com/?something1&something2&$something3&test=test4
                    // 1: google.com/?something11&something22&$something33&test=test4
                    // 2: google.com/?something111&something222&$something333&test=test4

                }
                if (allNames.length >= 2) {

                    var newForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                        title: 'Form',
                        width: 250,
                        autoHeight: true,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        bodyPadding: 10,
                        id: 'Form',
                    });


                    function newRadio() {
                        var radio = new Ext.form.Radio({
                            height: 40,
                            labelWidth: 110,
                            width: 20,
                            name: 'url',
                        });
                        return radio;
                    }


                    function newTextArea(id) {
                        var textArea = new Ext.form.TextArea({
                            fieldLabel: i + '_url',
                            height: 30,
                            labelWidth: 110,
                            width: 330,
                            submitValue: false,
                            readOnly: true,
                            autoScroll: true,
                            id: id
                        });
                        return textArea;
                    }


                    for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                        var id = i;
                        id = 'field_' + id;
                        var field = newTextArea(id);
                        var radioGr = newRadio();
                        var cont = NewContainer();
                        field.setValue(UrlArr);
                        newForm.add(cont);
                    }

                    function NewContainer() {
                        var container = new Ext.container.Container({
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            items: [radioGr, field]
                        });
                        return container;
                    }

                    var win = new Ext.Window({
                        title: "Window",
                        layout: 'fit',
                        modal: 'true',
                        height: 500,
                        width: 385,
                        items: [newForm],
                        buttons: [{
                            text: "Confirm",
                            handler: function() {
                                //something handler
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                    win.show();


                }
            }
```

Comment: I have provided an answer, can you check if it works for you or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues in your provided code like:

1. `Container` was getting created before `radio` and `textArea`.
2. Your requirement was to set the newUrl inside the field, but there is already a for loop in which this variable is getting updated and it is inside the scope of for loop. So instead you can define another variable as array above the first for loop and push the urls inside that array.

I have modified your code, refer below and provided a working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3crs) for your case.

```
var url = 'google.com/page1'
fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include',
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.text()
    })
    .then(function (html) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
        var value4 = 'test4';
        var UrlArr = [];
        if (condition) {
            var name = doc.querySelectorAll("someClass");
            for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                var allNames = name[i].outerHTML;
                var value1 = allNames.match('MyregExp1')[0];
                var value2 = allNames.match('MyregExp2')[0];
                var value3 = allNames.match('MYregExp3')[0];

                var newUrl = `google.com/?${value1}&${value2}&${value3}&test=${value4}`;

                console.log(value1);

                console.log(value2);

                console.log(value3);


                console.log(newUrl);
                UrlArr.push(newUrl);

            }
            if (allNames.length >= 2) {

                var newForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                    title: 'Form',
                    width: 250,
                    autoHeight: true,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    id: 'Form',
                });


                function newRadio() {
                    var radio = new Ext.form.Radio({
                        height: 40,
                        labelWidth: 110,
                        width: 20,
                        name: 'url',
                    });
                    return radio;
                }


                function newTextArea(id) {
                    var textArea = new Ext.form.TextArea({
                        fieldLabel: i + '_url',
                        height: 30,
                        labelWidth: 110,
                        width: 330,
                        submitValue: false,
                        readOnly: true,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        id: id
                    });
                    return textArea;
                }


                for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                    var id = i;
                    id = 'field_' + id;
                    var field = newTextArea(id);
                    var radioGr = newRadio();
                    var cont = NewContainer();
                    field.setValue(UrlArr[i]);
                    newForm.add(cont);
                }

                function NewContainer() {
                    var container = new Ext.container.Container({
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        items: [radioGr, field]
                    });
                    return container;
                }

                var win = new Ext.Window({
                    title: "Window",
                    layout: 'fit',
                    modal: 'true',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 385,
                    items: [newForm],
                    buttons: [{
                        text: "Confirm",
                        handler: function () {}
                    }]
                });
                win.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it doesnt work, when i console.log(UrlArr) it double it, i should get one array with 3 urls, but i get 3 arrays with 3 urls and the ext window doesnt show, code only generate array urls then stop :(

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle that I have attached ? It contains the window with panel having those fields, so is that correct ?

Comment: if thats correct, then the above code is also same.

Comment: You can contact me via chat if you are facing trouble.

Comment: I just update my code, can you see why its generate multiple arrays?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230748/discussion-between-dmitriy-andreevich-and-wahab-memon).